# Terraform GCP - Arguments pass in windows-startup-script-ps1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

In Terraform for GCP VM provision, I need to Run PowerShell script for disk partition as a startup. It requires 2 arguments as array for DriveName & DriveLetters.

```
    windows-startup-script-ps1 = "${file("disk.ps1") ('Logs','Files') ('M','S')"
```

it doesn't work, can you help how to give arguments to Powershell in Terraform startup script for VM provision.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the public documentation from GCP about [startup scripts on Windows VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/windows#metadata-keys) the metadata keys that can be used for the disk partition needs to be the correct as the following, you need to compare if is need it to execute a command or a script.

[image]

To declare the metadata in the main.tf file can be used the next block as an example.

```
  metadata = {
    windows-startup-script-cmd = <<-EOF
      "$${file("disk.ps1") ('Logs','Files') ('M','S')"
    EOF
  }
```

This is an argument inside the [google_compute_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#metadata) block.

Multiline strings can use shell-style ["here doc"](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/variables.html#strings) syntaxin terraform, with the string starting with a marker like <<-EOF and then the string ending with EOF on a line of its own.